# Applying the scroll animation on key press to be the same as it’s on mouse click

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, keyboard-events, animateplus

I have a horizontally spread page that one can scroll by mouse clicking, or by pressing <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up / Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left Arrow / Right Arrow</kbd>, and <kbd>Home / End</kbd> keys.

The scrolling that’s activated with mouse clicks is animated using `Animate Plus`.

**How can I have exactly the same animations when scrolling with key presses?**

Since my code won’t run in Stack Overflow’s snippet, I posted it to Codepen.

> Here’s my complete code:
>
> https://codepen.io/boletrone/pen/MWWZrPQ

And below is my JavaScript code:

```js
import animate from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animateplus@2/animateplus.js"

// Scroll on key presses
// =====================

let scrollPosition = 0
const maxScrollPosition = document.body.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth
const container = document.scrollingElement

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeydown = event => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "Space":
      case "PageDown":
      case "ArrowRight":
      case "ArrowDown": {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (scrollPosition === maxScrollPosition) return // If at the end, return
        scrollPosition += window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "PageUp":
      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "ArrowUp": {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (scrollPosition === 0) return // If at the beginning, return
        scrollPosition -= window.innerWidth
        break
      }
      case "Home": {
        scrollPosition = 0
        break
      }
      case "End": {
        scrollPosition = container.scrollWidth
        break
      }
    }

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollPosition
    })
  }
}

// Scroll on mouse clicks
// ======================

const goToPreviousSectionButton = document.createElement("button")
const goToNextSectionButton = document.createElement("button")

document.body.appendChild(goToPreviousSectionButton)
document.body.appendChild(goToNextSectionButton)

const sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section")).sort(
  (s1, s2) => {
    return s1.getBoundingClientRect().left - s2.getBoundingClientRect().left
  }
)

const getSectionInView = () => {
  const halfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2
  const index = sections.findIndex(
    section =>
      section.getBoundingClientRect().left <= halfWidth &&
      section.getBoundingClientRect().right > halfWidth
  )
  return index
}

const getNextSection = dir => {
  const sectionInViewIndex = getSectionInView()
  const nextIndex = sectionInViewIndex + dir
  const numSections = sections.length
  const nextSectionIndex =
    nextIndex < 0 || nextIndex >= numSections ? sectionInViewIndex : nextIndex
  return sections[nextSectionIndex]
}

const animateScroll = dir => {
  const from = container.scrollLeft
  const { left } = getNextSection(dir).getBoundingClientRect()
  return progress => (container.scrollLeft = from + progress * left)
}

goToPreviousSectionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  animate({
    easing: "out-quintic",
    change: animateScroll(-1)
  })
})

goToNextSectionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  animate({
    easing: "out-quintic",
    change: animateScroll(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Embrace and use better standards. `event.key`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hvala na savetu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ArrowRight** and **ArrowLeft** case in your "switch". 
The following usage will solve the problem.

```
import animate from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animateplus@2/animateplus.js"

// Scroll on key presses
// =====================

let scrollPosition = 0
const maxScrollPosition = document.body.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth
const container = document.scrollingElement

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeydown = event => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "Space":
      case "PageDown":
      case "ArrowRight":
        {
          scrollPosition++;
           if (scrollPosition === 3) return 
            event.preventDefault()
            animate({
              easing: "out-quintic",
              change: animateScroll(1)
            })
            break
        }
      case "ArrowLeft":
        {
            scrollPosition--;
           if (scrollPosition === 0) return 
            event.preventDefault()
            animate({
              easing: "out-quintic",
              change: animateScroll(-1)
            })
            break
        }
      case "PageUp": 
      case "Home": { 
        if(scrollPosition === 1)
         {
             animate({
              easing: "out-quintic",
              change: animateScroll(-1)
            }) 
         }else
         {
           animate({
             easing: "out-quintic",
             change: animateScroll(-2)
           })
         } 
        scrollPosition = 0;
        break
      }
      case "End": { 
         if(scrollPosition === 1)
         {
             animate({
              easing: "out-quintic",
              change: animateScroll(1)
            })  
         }else
           {
               animate({
                easing: "out-quintic",
                change: animateScroll(2)
              })
           }

        scrollPosition = 2;
        break
      }
    }


  }
}

// Scroll on mouse clicks
// ======================

const goToPreviousSectionButton = document.createElement("button")
const goToNextSectionButton = document.createElement("button")

document.body.appendChild(goToPreviousSectionButton)
document.body.appendChild(goToNextSectionButton)

const sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section")).sort(
  (s1, s2) => {
    return s1.getBoundingClientRect().left - s2.getBoundingClientRect().left
  }
)

const getSectionInView = () => {
  const halfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2
  const index = sections.findIndex(
    section =>
      section.getBoundingClientRect().left <= halfWidth &&
      section.getBoundingClientRect().right > halfWidth
  )
  return index
}

const getNextSection = dir => {
  const sectionInViewIndex = getSectionInView()
  const nextIndex = sectionInViewIndex + dir
  const numSections = sections.length
  const nextSectionIndex =
    nextIndex < 0 || nextIndex >= numSections ? sectionInViewIndex : nextIndex
  return sections[nextSectionIndex]
}

const animateScroll = dir => {
  const from = container.scrollLeft
  const { left } = getNextSection(dir).getBoundingClientRect()
  return progress => (container.scrollLeft = from + progress * left)
}

goToPreviousSectionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  animate({
    easing: "out-quintic",
    change: animateScroll(-1)
  })
})

goToNextSectionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  animate({
    easing: "out-quintic",
    change: animateScroll(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Everything works, except `Home` and `End` keys don’t take you to beginning or the end. Can you help with that?

Comment: Sure. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: Can u check now ?

Comment: Hey Jimmy, sincerely thanks for the effort. Now the problem is that if I add more sections, `End` doesn’t scroll to the end of document, since you hardcoded the number of sections to three.